# How to move a Pricebook and its Products from sandbox to production?

Tags: data-loader, data-export, pricebook, import

As the title suggests, I have created a `pricebook` with a list of `products` and their prices in my sandbox.
I would like to know how I can export this data into my production instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automated deployment process here.
This is a data migration task from the sandbox to the production org. As the data is inter-related there is an element of data transformation needed to complete the task. Ideally you should test this process before applying it to production.

You have the following entities:

- Products (Product2)
- PriceBooks (PriceBook2)
- PriceBookEntries

The general principle is as below,  ultimately you need to transform all Sandbox Ids into Produciton Ids so that the data still relates together corretly.

1. First migrate your pricebooks, if you have only created one or two of these, then it is likely easier to re-key than migrate.
2. Create a mapping/conversion table (in excel or SQL) of the pricebooks, including the standard pricebook.
3. Export the Products from Sandbox, and load these into Production.
4. Using the dataloader success file, you now have a mapping table this contains the sandbox id and the new production id for each product.
5. Export priceBookEntries from Sandbox, and swap out the Product2Id and the PriceBook2ID with your mapping tables to replace with equivalent Production Ids (using excel vlookup or SQL)

Answer (score 2):

This required you to use a data migration tool. 
Apex Data Loader is the default choice, but I have found myself using DataLoader.io quite a lot in the recently.

Here are the steps:

1. Extract the data from the following tables. Product2, PriceBook, PriceBook Entry.  (Refer)

[image: Product and Price book Relations]

2. Import the Product and Pricebook Data into Production first and save the success files. (This is for maintaining the new salesforce id, if you dont have the success files, you can re-extract the inserted records and get the new IDs)
3. Use Excel / or anything similar to update the Reference ID's for Product and Pricebook in the PricebookEntry Data you   had extracted in Step 1
4. Upload the PricebookEntry to production. (If there are errors, check that the reference id's are correct)

After everything is done, make sure that the pricebook you have uploaded is marked as Active and is selectable while adding opportunity products.

Comment: I am trying to use Dataloader.io to import the objects, but I've noticed when trying to map the fields some fields need to be manually mapped even though they are standard fields.. but the problem is I cannot find the same field in the available fields to map. There is a number of them as well such as `created by ID`, `Deleted`, `Price Book ID`

Comment: Created, LastModified are audit fields and not editable (unless you raise a case with support), deleted is not createable. PriceBook2Id on the PricebookEntry object should be createable.

Comment: Okaay I know why some are not shown, it is because Dataloader.io can only insert/update to fields that are shown in the page template

Comment: @imran That is incorrect! you can use dataloader.io to load data into any fields on an object. You can not insert data into fields which are not editable. This is true for any tool you use.

Comment: Hmm strange,  a field that I had visible and editable by the system administrator but wasnt displayed on the page layout could not be found by dataloader.io initially but when I added it to the page layout it was map-able.